# How to use AWS S3 async in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I'm using this package: https://async-aws.com/integration/laravel.html#illuminate-filesystem

But it seems using `s3` and `async-aws-s3` as filesystem driver have no difference. I've tested uploading using `Storage::put()` with large and small file size and the execution time is the same (15mb around 1.6sec) - (0.5mb around 0.5sec)..

Am I using this correctly? Is changing `async-aws-s3` enough to make `Storage::put()` upload asynchronously?